# How to get element by class name using jQuery in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, jquery

I am able to load the jQuery library, but it seems that I can't call some simple jQuery function:

```
window.jQuery('.classText').attr('id');
```

I am trying to get element id by finding the element by class name. Using above script I always get `undefined`. But using online playground like jsfiddle, I am able to get the element id

Here is the detail of my js and html file

ItemToApprove.js:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript,loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

import jqueryPkg from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquerypackage';

export default class ItemToApprove extends LightningElement {
    @track error;

    dataTablejsInitialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.dataTablejsInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.dataTablejsInitialized = true;

        loadScript(this, jqueryPkg +'/jQuery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.js')
        .then(() => {
            this.error = undefined;

            //calling the jquery function
            this.initializeTable();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
    }

    initializeTable() {
        //always getting undefined instead of printing the element id
        alert(window.jQuery('.classText').attr('id')); 
    }
}
```

ItemToApprove.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Item to Approve" icon-name="action:new_task">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <input id="txtTest" class="classText" type="text" value="test" />
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Basically I want to get the element using jQuery function by element class name. How can I achieve this in LWC?

Comment: Using the `window.` / `document.` is not recommended in Web Components? LWC has its own way of doing DOM manipulations, why there is a need to use JQuery, is there any specific reason?

Comment: I'm trying to apply table into jQuery datatable, can you show me what is the best practice instead of using `window.` / `document.`?

Comment: I'm following this example:
https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsChartjs/libsChartjs.js. I thought when we are using 3rd party library, we need to explicitly calling window. `this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use jquery (or any 3rd party JS library), it is better to pass the native lightning selector to jquery - without which there is a chance you will run into problems with any of upgrades. In your case, you can use `this.template.querySelector('.classText')`. Below code will work:

```
window.jQuery(this.template.querySelector('.classText')).attr('id');
```

Below is full code:

```
renderedCallback() {
    if (this.dataTablejsInitialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.dataTablejsInitialized = true;

    loadScript(this, jqueryPkg + '/jQuery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.js')
        .then(() => {
            this.error = undefined;

            //calling the jquery function
            this.initializeTable();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
}
initializeTable() {
    console.log('classText id => ', window.jQuery(this.template.querySelector('.classText')).attr('id'));
}
```

However, note that id will be modified at [RUNTIME](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_dom_work).

> Don’t use ID selectors with querySelector. The IDs that you define in
>   HTML templates may be transformed into globally unique values when the
>   template is rendered. If you use an ID selector in JavaScript, it
>   won’t match the transformed ID.

So, the id you get will be something like **txtTest-101**

Comment: Understood, we will not using the Id as reference. We just trying to figure out how to get the element. Thanks for pointing it out!